# mocha tests with ES6 style imports

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a Mocha test with some ES6 style imports in the file but I keep getting the error:

```
import assert from 'assert';
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I tried to invoke mocha with both 
`mocha --require @babel/register --recursive` 
and 
`mocha --require babel-register --recursive` 
but the error would not go away.

What is the correct way to run ES6 style Mocha tests?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming from Google:

You can also install esm:  `npm i esm --save-dev` or use your preferred package manager.

Then pass it as an argument to mocha: `mocha 'index.test.js' --require esm`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. [Here's a simple repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sun-s0fu5). If you click `+`in the terminal and then type `npm test` it fails with "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" even though the test command is `mocha --require esm test`

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my question here -> https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei

This package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mochatest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register --recursive"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

together with this .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try Below Code

```
import { strict as assert } from 'assert';
```

Or

```
import * as assert from 'assert';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In one case I get an `Unexpected token {` error and in the other case I get and `Unexpected token *` error so unfortunately that does not solve the problem.

Comment: cannot find module assert.